# Call function from UICollectionViewCell to use in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell that creates a bunch of text fields and a function (handleNewJob) that looks at all the textfields created in the cell and writes them to firebase.

However, what I want is for a button that I have created in my UICollectionView to call the function (handleNewJob) from the UICollectionViewCell.

Is this possible? I have tried having the function inside the UICollectionView but I can't seem to reference all the textfields.text?

Here is my function inside UICollectionViewCell (I haven't included all the textfield generation as it's quite long):

```
        // HANDLE NEW JOB
        func handleNewJob(){
            let newJobBrand = jobBrand.text!
            let newJobName = jobName.text!
            let newDirectorName = directorName.text!
            let newAgencyName = agencyName.text!
            let newProdCoName = prodCoName.text!
            // WHERE TO PUT IN DATABASE
            let reference = Database.database().reference().child("jobInfo")
            let childRef = reference.childByAutoId()
            // REFERENCING DICTIONARY
            let jobBrandValue = ["jobBrand": newJobBrand]
            let jobNameValue = ["jobName": newJobName]
            let jobDirectorValue = ["directorName": newDirectorName]
            let jobAgencyNameValue = ["agencyName": newAgencyName]
            let jobProdCoValue = ["prodCoName": newProdCoName]
            // WRITE TO DATABASE
            childRef.updateChildValues(jobBrandValue)
            childRef.updateChildValues(jobNameValue)
            childRef.updateChildValues(jobDirectorValue)
            childRef.updateChildValues(jobAgencyNameValue)
            childRef.updateChildValues(jobProdCoValue)
        }
```

Here is my code for the UICollectionView - I want to call the function under the handleNext button:

```
          import UIKit
      import Firebase

      class page_newJobSwipingController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

          // VARIABLES
          var ref:DatabaseReference?

              // BOTTOM BUTTONS
          private let previousButton: UIButton = {
              let button = UIButton(type: .system)
              button.setTitle("Previous", for: .normal)
              button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
              button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
              button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePrev), for: .touchUpInside)
              button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              return button
          }()
          private let nextButton: UIButton = {
              let button = UIButton(type: .system)
              button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
              button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
              let pinkColour = UIColor(red: 232/255, green: 68/266, blue: 133/255, alpha: 1)
              button.setTitleColor(.mainPink, for: .normal)
              button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleNext), for: .touchUpInside)
              return button
          }()

              // SET UP NEXT AND PREVIOUS BUTTONS TO HAVE A FUNCTION
          @IBAction func handlePrev(sender : UIButton) {
              let prevIndex = max(pageControl.currentPage - 1, 0)
              pageControl.currentPage = prevIndex
              let indexPath = IndexPath(item: prevIndex, section: 0)
              collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
          }
          @IBAction func handleNext(sender : UIButton) {
              let nextIndex = pageControl.currentPage + 1
              pageControl.currentPage = nextIndex
              if nextIndex == 1 {
                  print ("move to page 2")
              } else {
                  print ("send alert message")
                  newJobCellGeneral.handleNewJob()
                  storyboardAlert()
              }

              let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
              collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
          }

          // HANDLE UPLOAD STORYBOARD OPTIONS
          @IBAction func storyboardAlert() {

              let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
              imagePickerController.delegate = self
              // ACTION SHEET FOR ADDING NEW ATTACHMENT
              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Job Created", message: "Do you want to upload storyboard cells now?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Now", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                  let storyboardUpload = page_newJobStoryboardUpload()
                  self.show(storyboardUpload, sender: self)
              }))
              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Later", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                  let jobList = page_jobList()
                  self.show(jobList, sender: self)
              }))
              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
              self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }

              // PAGE CONTROL
          private let pageControl: UIPageControl = {
              let pc = UIPageControl()
              pc.numberOfPages = 2
              pc.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .mainPink
              pc.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 207/266, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1)
              return pc
          }()
          override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
              let x = targetContentOffset.pointee.x
              pageControl.currentPage = Int(x / view.frame.width)
          }
              // CONSTRAINTS OF BOTTOM CONTROLS
          fileprivate func setupBottomControls(){
              let bottomControlsStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [previousButton, pageControl, nextButton])

              bottomControlsStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              bottomControlsStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
              view.addSubview(bottomControlsStackView)

              NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                  bottomControlsStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
                  bottomControlsStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                  bottomControlsStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                  bottomControlsStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
                  ])
          }

          // SUPER VIEW DID LOAD
          override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()

              collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
              collectionView?.register(newJobCellGeneral.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "newJobCellGeneral")
              collectionView?.register(newJobCellTechnical.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "newJobCellTechnical")
              collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

              setupBottomControls()

          }
          func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
              return 0
          }
          override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
              return 2
          }
          override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

              if indexPath.item == 0 {

                  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newJobCellGeneral", for: indexPath) as! newJobCellGeneral
                  navigationItem.title = "General Info"
                  return cell
              } else {
                  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newJobCellTechnical", for: indexPath) as! newJobCellTechnical
                  navigationItem.title = "Technical Specs"
                  return cell
              }
          }
          func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
              return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flow is inversed but yes, the easiest way is via notifications
in you collection view

Put this in your collectionView button pressed method

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("handleNewJob"), object: nil)
```

Add observer in you collection view cell (init or awakeFromNib depends)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNewJob, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "handleNewJob"), object: nil)
```

Comment: Once I add these 2 lines, what do I put into my `handleNext` Button to call the function? I only want to call the function when the button is pressed. I have this at the moment `newJobCellGeneral.handleNewJob()` and I am getting the error **Instance member 'handleNewJob' cannot be used on type 'newJobCellGeneral'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?**

Comment: This code worked - however instead of putting the first line into the viewDidLoad, I put it into my button function so it only gets called when tapped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Notification Center is one solution, but the easier way is to be able to call a function on your collection view controller directly from the cell.

To do that, you need to be able to reference your parent view controller. so add this UIView extension:

Create a swift file named UIView.swift and paste this:

```
import UIKit
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if parentResponder is UIViewController {
                return parentResponder as! UIViewController!
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

then from your cell, for example when a button is clicked:

```
@IBAction func someButtonAction(sender : UIButton) {
    let parent = self.parentViewController as! page_newJobSwipingController

    parent.whateverFunction()
}
```

Comment: I have put the first block of code at the bottom of my UICollectionViewController and the second block of code into my Cell above the the function. However I am getting these errors in cell. For the let line **Value of type '(newJobCellGeneral) -> () -> (newJobCellGeneral)' has no member 'parent'** and the second line **Expected declaration**.

Comment: create a new swift file named UIViewExtention (but this name doesn't really matter) and put the first block of code inside it.
Then inside your cell, where you want to call the function on the parent, use the second block of code.

Comment: I have made the new UIViewExtension and copied the first block in. When I copy the second block of text into my UIViewCollectionViewCell (class name: newJobCellGeneral) I get this error `Value of type 'newJobCellGeneral' has no member 'parent'`.

Comment: Don't worry about the error I have fixed it. Thank you for your help - I found that @zheck answer worked easily once the code was in the correct place.

Comment: Because you are probably missing the line let parent = self.parentViewController as! page_newJobSwipingController in the same function